# Loading properties in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working in a project where I inherited a lot of code with some decisions that I have to live with, but some I have to change. One of them there are a lot of hardcoded values for hostnames. The project is a chrome extension.
I am trying to load properties, such as backend host names in my chrome extension. I know that there is a way to load a JSON file like [this](https://dev.to/aussieguy/reading-files-in-a-chrome-extension--2c03), however, this is async and I don't believe that it will work for me.
So I created a JS file that has the properties `config.js` in the form of an object like so:

```
const config = {
    "envs":{
        "dev": {
            "protocol": "https",
            ...
         }
     }
};
export {config as default};
```

But then I realized that I have some JS files that are modules and they can make user of `import` statements and others are not modules. So you can have background.html looking like this:

```
<script src="/libs/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/paho-mqtt.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="myscript1.js"></script>
<script src="myscript2.js"></script>
<script src="myscript3.js"></script>
```

Imagine that `myscript1.js` above needs to grab a value from the `config.js` I mentioned. It will `import config from "config.js"`. But then what if `myscript2.js` or `myscript3.js` need to read that same config, what do I do? 2 and 3 are classic scripts and therefore I can not use imports. I feel like I am missing something so obvious.
Any ideas? thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) Use a bundler like webpack which will handle all of the different script types out-of-the-box or a simpler build tool which will inline the contents of the config file instead of a special comment, 2) Simply load this script without import/export so it runs first and creates a global `config` variable which you can use anywhere (you can add it to globals in eslint config). 3) Store it as json and use the deprecated *synchronous* XHR to read it.

Comment: @wOxxOm if you have any sample code or can point to one, it would be most appreciated

Comment: I don't use bundlers so I can't help with 1. As for 2 you already use the same approach for other script, and 3 is easy to find by googling.